# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

Buen día, cuando intento consultar un folio en mi formulario me sale un error que dice:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Aquí mi código:

```
<?php
$serverName = "10.21.22.16"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Siec", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"k115");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$result="";
if(array_key_exists("search",$_POST)){
$consul= 'SELECT SOL.FOLIO, SOL.ESTATUSPAG, SV.TOTALP, CS.SERVICIO 
FROM 
SOLICITU SOL
INNER JOIN SERVSOL SV ON SV.FOLIO=SOL.FOLIO
INNER JOIN  CATSERV CS ON CS.SERVS = SV.SERVS
WHERE SOL.FOLIO = ?';
$stmt=$conn->prepare($consul);
$result=$stmt->execute(array($_POST['folio']));
$result=$stmt->fetch();
if(empty($result)){
$result = "No se encontraron resultados!!";
}
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<label for="folio">folio: </label>
<input type="text" name="folio" id="folio"/>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Buscar" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
<?php
if( !empty($result) ) {
?>
<p><strong>folio</strong>: <?php echo $result['folio'];?></p>
<p><strong>Estatus Pagado</strong>: <?php echo $result['Estatuspag'];?></p>
<p><strong>Total</strong>: <?php echo $result['Totalp'];?></p>
<p><strong>Servicio</strong>: <?php echo $result['SERVICIO'];?></p>
<?php
}
?>
</html>
```

es justo en esa linea donde me marca el error

> $stmt=$conn->prepare($consul);

Sabrá alguien por qué?
Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que tu problema se encuentra en la conexión, puedes usar el ejemplo de la documentación oficial y verificar si la conexión se realizó con éxito

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

La variable `$conn` está retornando `FALSE` y no un recurso, por eso te muestra el error

**EDITO:**

Tu error es porque la variable `$conn` es de tipo `resource` no `object`

Si revisamos la documentación oficial, para realizar una consulta preparada necesitas usar la funcion [sqlsrv_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php)

Resumiendo tu código va así:

```
$serverName = "10.21.22.16"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Siec", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"k115");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$result="";
if(array_key_exists("search",$_POST))
{
    $consul= "SELECT 
                  SOL.FOLIO, 
                  SOL.ESTATUSPAG, 
                  SV.TOTALP, 
                  CS.SERVICIO 
              FROM 
                  SOLICITU SOL
                  INNER JOIN SERVSOL SV ON SV.FOLIO=SOL.FOLIO
                  INNER JOIN  CATSERV CS ON CS.SERVS = SV.SERVS
              WHERE SOL.FOLIO = ?";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $consul, array($_POST['folio']));

    if( !$stmt ) 
    {
        $result = "Error en la consulta";
        //die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) === false ) 
    {
      $result = "No se encontraron resultados!!";
      //die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    else
    {
        $result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)
    }            

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
}
```

Por otro lado, te recomiendo que uses [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php) el cual también tiene soporte para MS SQL

Usando POO es mucho mas fácil y tu código quedaría algo así:

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=10.21.22.16;Database=Siec','sa','k115');

if(array_key_exists("search",$_POST))
{
    $consul= "SELECT 
                  SOL.FOLIO, 
                  SOL.ESTATUSPAG, 
                  SV.TOTALP, 
                  CS.SERVICIO 
              FROM 
                  SOLICITU SOL
                  INNER JOIN SERVSOL SV ON SV.FOLIO=SOL.FOLIO
                  INNER JOIN  CATSERV CS ON CS.SERVS = SV.SERVS
              WHERE SOL.FOLIO = ?";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($consul);
    $folio = $_POST['folio'];
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $folio, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if( !$stmt->execute() ) 
    {
        $result = "Error en la consulta";
    }
    else
    {
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }            

}
```

Puedes leer la documentación oficial de [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) para aclarar cualquier duda :)

Comment: Ya lo hice, incluso lo tenía en un principio y me dice conexión exitosa, si creo que sea el $conn pero es por otra razón, pero no he averiguado cuál!

Comment: @Augustoock entiendo, puedes observar que realice una modificación a mi respuesta, cuéntame si esto te sirve

Comment: Genial amigo, enserio era lo que buscaba hacerolo con PDO, creí que habría soporte MS SQL, y disculpa no pude contestar ya que tenía mucho trabajo, y aunque me ha ayudado me arroja otro error, al parecer ahora es al momento de arrojar el resultado `Warning: Illegal string offset 'folio' in` así en los demas EstatusPag, Totalp y Servicio, alguna idea, disculpa las molestias y gracias :)

Comment: Perdón, olvide que la función `bindParam` solo admite variables no puedes pasar esto `$_POST['folio']`  voy a agregar la corrección.

Answer (score 2):

Tu sentencia nunca va funcionar porque se te ha olvidado algunos pasos importantes, uno es, `bind_param()`, allí es donde te arroja el error, debes pasar el parámetro de tu *WHERE SOL.FOLIO = ?*, es decir, tu variable `$_POST['folio']`

> **[mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)** -- mysqli_stmt_bind_param — Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parámetros

**Especificación del tipo de caracteres**
i   la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero
d   la variable correspondiente es de tipo double
s   la variable correspondiente es de tipo string
b   la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes

**Ejemplo actualizado:**

```
$consul= 'SELECT SOL.FOLIO, SOL.ESTATUSPAG, SV.TOTALP, CS.SERVICIO 
FROM 
SOLICITU SOL
INNER JOIN SERVSOL SV ON SV.FOLIO=SOL.FOLIO
INNER JOIN  CATSERV CS ON CS.SERVS = SV.SERVS
WHERE SOL.FOLIO = ?';    
$stmt=$conn->prepare($consul);
$stmt->bind_param("Especificación del tipo de caracteres", $tu_variable_folio);
$stmt->execute();
//Transfiere un conjunto de resulados de la última consulta
$stmt->store_result();
//Comprobamos si existen registros en la Base de datos.
if($stmt->num_rows>0){
  //Vincula variables a una sentencia preparada para el almacenamiento de resultados.
  $stmt->bind_result($FOLIO,$ESTATUSPAG,$TOTALP,$SERVICIO);//Lo que has seleccionado en tu SELECT
  $stmt->fetch();
  //Ya puedes trabajar con tus datos desde la Base de datos.
} else {
   echo 'Se encontaron 0 resultados.";
}
$stmt->close();//Cerramos sentencia.
```

Tu `HTML` quedaría así:

```
<p><strong>folio</strong>: <?php echo $FOLIO;?></p>
<p><strong>Estatus Pagado</strong>: <?php echo $ESTATUSPAG;?></p>
<p><strong>Total</strong>: <?php echo $TOTALP;?></p>
<p><strong>Servicio</strong>: <?php echo $SERVICIO;?></p>
```

Manual PHP [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

> **Nota:** también debes tener en cuenta el correcto orden de tus parámetros para crear tu conexión.

Ejemplo:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
```